# How to import facebook contacts to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I'm new to iPhone development. I need to display facebook contacts to UITableView of my application. I'm not familiar with the webservice features of iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Facebook Connect for iPhone (from Facebook) http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/213/

The Facebook Connect framework provides a class simply called "Facebook" with a method for making FQL requests. FQL requests can be used to retrieve friends lists, and much more.

```
- (FBRequest*)requestWithMethodName:(NSString *)methodName // @"fql.query"
                          andParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
                      andHttpMethod:(NSString *)httpMethod      // "POST"
                        andDelegate:(id <FBRequestDelegate>)delegate;
```

See FQL's documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/